# Slow DirectX frame rate

Tags: c++, directx

Does anyone know the best way to slow the frame rate of a scene without slowing the camera movement. I basically want to debug some key frame animations but not effect the camera.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: If your rendering is separate from your camera and update logic, then you could update once a second, but keep camera and rendering at high fps.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick reply. I didn't create the base application so ill have to have a dig thorough. From the looks of it render function is separate from my camera matrices.

Comment: I jsut wondered if there was a constant that could be changed that told directX to throttle the FPS.

Comment: There might be... from memory FRAPS has something which allows you to cap FPS while you're recording... and if you're after debugging stuff, recording what's going on just might be a good idea

Comment: hmm yea I think changing the fps will effect the camera. Ill have to have a look in the monring. getting late !

Comment: you shouldn't bind your animations to your FPS, they should run off something increases at a constant rate, like time (which would make slowing them down or speeding them up trivial).

Comment: Yeah, thats what i'm looking for. like i said i didn't write the base code so itll take some digging. Thanks for the tip @necrolis

Comment: @Necrolis I ended up doing what you suggested. if you leave it as answer I can mark it closed.